# Is there a way to merge layers in keras with different sample/batch sizes and a question about merged layers

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have looked for an answer my specific question but have not come across anything so posting here. Any help would be much appreciated!

I have two questions about merging layers in keras. I have built a model that concatenates a layer between two models before an output. Because of the nature of my data, the inputs (sample sizes) from both sides will be different, however merging layers would be beneficial as two sources of data will both belong to the same classes in the data and so it would be nice to see how classification is taking place when two models share data before the output.

I would like to know if there is a way of using different sample sizes from both sides as i get an array length error when fitting the model if the data are different sizes.

The way i have counteracted this is to make the left branch of the model (whose input sample size is smaller than the right side data)the same length as the right side by simply duplicating data until the right dimensions are reached, i.e,

train left: 140 samples, train right 180 samples... for train left, i add rows 1:40 to the bottom of the data to make it 180 samples.

Is this a sufficient way to counteract this problem?

My code for the model is as follows:

```
left_branch_input = Input(shape=(5078,), name='Left_input')
left_branch_output = Dense(64, activation='relu', name="middle_layer")(left_branch_input)
left_branch_output_2=Dense(32, activation="relu", name="second_layer")(left_branch_output)
left_branch_output_3=Dense(100, activation="relu", name="penultimate_layer")(left_branch_output_2)

right_branch_input = Input(shape=(5078,), name='right_input')
right_branch_output = Dense(64, activation='relu', name="middle_layerR")(right_branch_input)
right_branch_output_2=Dense(32, activation="relu", name="second_layerR")(right_branch_output)
right_branch_output_3=Dense(100, activation="relu", name="penultimate_layerR")(right_branch_output_2)

concat = concatenate([left_branch_output_3, right_branch_output_3], name='Concatenate')

final_model_output = Dense(24, activation='sigmoid')(concat)
final_model = Model(inputs=[left_branch_input, right_branch_input], outputs=final_model_output,
                    name='Final_output' )


final_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])


sum_vector = np.array(y_train.astype(bool) + y_trainSC.astype(bool), dtype=int)

historyMerged=final_model.fit([X_train, X_trainSC], sum_vector,
          epochs=200,
          verbose=1,
          validation_split=0.15,
          callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)], shuffle=True)
```

The model compiles and fits and the performance is good, however as a sanity check I would just like to ask if the approach of appending samples (by duplicated[length required] is ok? Is there a way of ignoring the sample size from the different branches?

As this is a binary_crossentropy multi-label problem, the orders of the sample inb oth data sets do not overlap perectly. For example, row is organ 1 age 1 for the left branch and for the right branch the first sample is organ 2 age 2. Does this matter? or is the model working by the class according to the one-hot encoded data as this is what should actually matter right? the class it exists in as oppose to the order... the model.predict function actually gets the data right for both data sets, so presumably, for the data that is the same in left and right branches, the merge layers are using weights from both branches to find similarities and features that improve classification:

Finally, I have a question about the model summary for the merged layer.

Any help and advice on this would be much appreciated! I am pleased with the performance thus far but want to be absolutely sure that the order as well duplicated data is a valid way of approaching this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your question is how to concatenate tensors with different shapes. This is a simple example you can run in Colab:

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import *

in_a = Input(shape=(10,))
in_b = Input(shape=(20,))
join = Concatenate(axis=1)([in_a, in_b])
h1 = Dense(10)(join)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(h1)
model = Model([in_a, in_b], out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.summary()
```

The key is the "axis" parameter to Concatenate.

I'm not sure I understand your second question. The features in left and right branches do not need to correlate at all. These could be completely different.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response! actually i more would like to have a concatenation layer as in my initial post. I am comfortable with the formation of this. But when i fit the model, I have to make the both training datasets the same length otherwise it throws an error: so i make the shortest training data the same by duplicating the rows at the end until they are the same length. Is it true that the training set from the left and training set from the right (when fitting the model) do not need to match? so row one of trainleft branch does not have to be of the same as the right?

Comment: You can have multiple inputs into a model. Their batch_size shape (dimension 0) must match. The other dimensions can be different. You can even mix multiple different dimensions as long as the batch size is the same. For instance, it is not uncommon to have a sequence of shape (batch_size, sequence_len, n_features) and a second input of shape (batch_size, m_features).

Comment: for example, row 1 in the left branch training doesn't have to be word description of dog and row 1 of the right training data doesn't have to be an image of a dog right? as long as the one-hot encoding is done correctly, because its a binary_crossentropy the order of the training data from both branches doesn't have to match? is that correct just to clarify? many thanks!!

Comment: yes thank you that makes perfect sense!! so if the two do not match, is it ok to duplicate data to address this issue? and then, as above, is it correct that the rows do not have match as long ad the one-hot encoding is ok?

Comment: The multiple inputs have to be about the same example. i.e. row N of the left input and row N of the right input have to be about the same object. The information can be whatever data you collect as long as it is expressible as a tensor.

Comment: Maybe this example can clarify your questions: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models

Comment: ok thank you so much! yes that makes sense also. Is there an alternative then to overcome this problem? as the information i have on the right contains only a subset of data (just in a different form) from the left. so for example, on the left i will have 6 ages, and on the right i may only have 1 (more in the future).. so row n left and row n right will never match. however, i would like to merge layers as i would like to understand how features are common for age x (for example) from the left and right... is there no way this can be overcome?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your scenario. There is no reason to pass duplicate information as input to the network. When you say that the rows do not match it is unclear whether they are about different examples (which doesn't make sense) or that they contain different features of the same example (which is the only reasonable thing to do).

Comment: sorry for the confusion! this is genomic data. genomic data from the left and right side will be different.. measuring proteins on the right branch and gene expression on the left. so as an example, data in the left may be 6 ages 12 organs. data on the right may be 3 ages 5 organs. but the 3 ages and 5 organs on the right will be the same as the other 3 ages and 5 organs on the left. its just that the left will contain other organs and other ages. equally, there may be data for say 800 samples (batch size 800) on the left.. and say 1000 on the right... I still want to be able to merge layers..

Comment: or models as we need to be able to understand the correlation between proteins and genes.. so sharing weights from two models for common features is something I will need to do... does that make more sense? so i would like to see for the ages and organs that are present on the right as on the left,, the weights that contribute to class activation.. even though there isnt a 1:1 mapping from the left and right.. the data on the right will be common (for some samples) as on the left... instead of inferring similarities or differences i feel like this should be merged in keras...

Comment: From the model above, it seems that you want to be able to predict 24 (independent) probability values. All the input data necessary to do so needs to be batch of the same batch sample. So if you need 2 rows from database table A and 5 rows from database table B you need to flatten them into a single "example" for the neural network. You can divide this information into as many separate inputs as you choose (that is equivalent). But common NN architectures have no memory. It is fine if you end up with 100k features per sample; but you can mix rows from different inputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196221/discussion-between-user9317212-and-pedro-marques).

Comment: I know the accepted answer is not the right answer to your question now I have the same error could you please let me know how did you solve this problem?